# How to use the last returned value by a function, as an input for the same function in a loop. Python

Tags: python, function, loops, iteration

I have a problem using the last returned value from a function, as an input for the same function, I don´t know if it is possible to do.

For example, I have the following function:

```
def sample (x):
    p=1+x
    return p 
sample(h)
```

and I want to use the last returned value "p" as the new data for h in a loop, the new function will look like:

```
def sample (x):
    p=1+x
    return p 
sample(h)

for i in range (0,5):  
    h=sample(h)
```

The code works for iteration 1 and 2, but don´t update the values for iterations 3,4,5. Variable "p" in  my real code, takes values from other functions or databases and changes (it´s a 3d array too), so it changes with each iteration. First input data "h" comes from a previous function too.

The input and output will be like:

```
h= [[[1.71, 1.8,  1.32, 1.56, 2.81],   [1.,   2.,   1.,   2.,   1.]],
    [[1.44, 1.47, 1.5,  1.02, 2.51],   [1.,   2.,   1.,   2.,   1.]]]


p= [[[1.62, 1.15, 1.1,  1.05, 2.28],   [1.,   2.,   1.,   2.,   1.]],
    [[1.97, 1.85, 1.88, 1.03, 1.87],   [1.,   2.,   1.,   2.,   2.]]]
```

Comment: Can you please add an example for the output you gat and the output you expect?

Comment: yan ziselman, the output will be a 3d array like "p", the problem is that I´m always getting the same values after 2nd iteration, it's like the loop does not iterate over the last input value. Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't really make it clearer. the way i see it if you use your function on 'h' each value in h should increase by 1. but in your example only a few values change and not all of them increase by 1. Please try to isolate the required behavior from all the other operation you perform on the input in your example. like how did  the 2.51 change to 1.87 in position [1, 0, 4] in your example?

Comment: yan ziselman, thanks for your interest and your time. The values are changed randomly according to eligibility constraints using other functions. Actually, the answers provided previously worked great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
last_value = None
def sample (x):
    p=1+x
    last_value = p
    return p 
sample(last_value)

for i in range (0,5):  
    h=sample(last_value )
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to grasp from your description, but I believe this might give you the desired result:

```py
def sample(x):
    p = 1+x
    return p


h = 1  # Set the initial value here
for i in range(0, 5):
    newH = sample(h)
    h = newH
    print(h) # Remove this print statement if you do not wish the result printed
```

Comment: Your help was good too, thank you for your time and knowledge.